# simplexlsx out of memory

Tags: php, memory, xlsx

I am using simplexlsx class to read 38879 rows of data (on 1 sheet) and I had a problem with memory (Out of Memory). My server's memory size is 48 GIGS and I set the memory_limit (php.ini) on 9000MB, but the problem is still there! Can you tell me what I am supposed to do?

Comment: the error says : Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 83099648) (tried to allocate 34791104 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\class\xlsx.php on line 359

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the memory limit?

Comment: yes of course, not the server, but the php/apache service

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, sorry. You could try to split the file into parts first. Or just increase the limit and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

SimpleXLSX and PHPExcel are really good at a lot of things but are both terrible at reading large spreadsheets (you can't be good at everything!).

I was faced with the same issue and even when using the optimizations from PHPExcel (caching, reading chunks of data, ...), it did not work out. Out of memory errors were fixed but reading a not even large file took forever.

So I ended up creating a library to solve this scale issue. Give it a try and let me know if that helps: https://github.com/box/spout

Comment: this is an awesome library

Answer (score 0):

Bumping the limit is hardly a way to handle something that is running through several thousand rows of data--unless there's a specific reason. This is due to awful wastes of memory in code, a likely story with your situation would be that the script is creating a huge array (or object) of the rows. Rather than bumping the memory limit, I'd suggest altering the code to make it more memory efficient.

I've never heard of SimpleXLSX, but I have used PHPExcel, with which I've never encountered an issue. If it's not too much work for you to revamp using PHPExcel, I'd suggest using it.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: I am using PHPExcel because PHPExcel does the same issues too, I have try the caching method but it doesn't take any effect, still out of memory. Can you explain that?

Comment: Can you post the code for gathering data from the spreadsheet?

Comment: What you probably need to do, depending on the size of your spreadsheet, is read in "chunks". PHPExcel has documentation regarding this. I hate (HATE) the lack of documentation regarding reading line-by-line as if using fgetcsv() in PHP. PHPExcel says in their documentation that there is an in-memory representation of the sheet, which I am guessing includes the cell data by noting the toArray() method.

I think having only an in-memory approach is wasteful and stupid. Check this out: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/242712?ProjectName=phpexcel

Comment: I am sorry, the first comment it should be : "I am using SimpleXLSX because PHPExcel" (human error, sorry), I think there is no other way to solve this problematic ...